# Trouble understanding formulae describing Markov discrimination algorithm

Tags: algorithm, math, spam-prevention, discrete-mathematics

I've been poring over this paper (http://www.siefkes.net/papers/mrf-spamfiltering.pdf) for more than a few days now, but haven't been able to make sense of any of the formulas in section 3 or after.

In particular, I don't understand what these parts mean:

P(w|C(w) = s)
/*
The probability that a document is spam conditional on a given word in it being spam?
*/

P(w|C(w) = spam)
/*
Is that the same probability as the previous expression? Why "spam" instead of an 's' or vice versa?
*/

{Product operator with subscript "cliques c"} ({Product operator with subscript c} (w, spam))

/*
In the paper, the innermost expression is said to mean the local probability, but I don't understand the notation. Is the (w, spam) following the product operator an ordered set or a function? What would it be a function of?
*/

I don't understand any of the formulas with the binomial coefficients in them, either, but for those at least I think I know what I should begin reading.

Comment: I'm curious, in what context do you need these things? Are you just trying to use them in an implementation or is this research-related?

Comment: Kinda both. I'm making a usenet reader with built in spam filtering. I have a pretty standard Graham Baynesian filter implemented, which seems to work well, but I'm interested in this Markovian approach because of its purported superiority.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the first two, the first to me reads like it is meant to be `s` as a variable for s in S. The second only talks about C(w) = spam, which are the cases where s = spam. You can see this since they use Z_{s} and V^{s} in definitions, and Z_{spam} and C(w) = spam in the examples, so they demonstrated it for the case that C(w) = spam, but the definitions are meant to be general, i.e. covering both C(w) = spam and C(w) = nonspam.

Regarding this:

{Product operator with subscript "cliques c"} ({Product operator with subscript c} (w, spam))

The definition of (w,spam) is not given in set notation, but only informally in the paragraph directly before that term is used as `local probability for (w_{i}, w_{j}), given
C(w) = s`. I'm afraid I don't know what local probability means, I assume it has something to do with Markov theory?

About the weighting scheme definitions, I really have no idea.